# How can I find DDL statements run against Database/schemas

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have specific requirement where I need to find only DDL ran against my snowflake  database/schema during specific period of time , how can we find using query_history or any other method, any idea??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible using [QUERY_HISTORY](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/query_history.html):

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE(INFORMATION_SCHEMA.QUERY_HISTORY())
     -- END_TIME_RANGE_START/END_TIME_RANGE_END  to get specific time range
WHERE DATABASE_NAME ILIKE '<db_name>'
  AND SCHEMA_NAME   ILIKE '<schema_name>'
  AND QUERY_TYPE    ILIKE ANY ('CREATE%', 'ALTER%', 'DROP%', 'DESCRIBE%');
```

The `QUERY_TYPE` column contains values that are more descriptive like: `CREATE_VIEW/CREATE_TABLE_AS_SELECT/CRATE_TABLE/ALTER_TABLE_ADD_COLUMN` etc.

To retrieve entire class of [DDL commands](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql-ddl-summary.html), wildcard pattern was used `CREATE%` or `ALTER%`. It could be further tweaked depending on specific needs.

Comment: Thanks @Lukasz Szozda